# Is it illegal to make a puppy fur jacket?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, animals, pets, food-processing

I watched 101 Dalmatians for the first time and wander: Can dogs or cats be raised like farm animals for the purpose of food or fur? What species of animal is not allowed for product other than endangered species?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### USA:

[19 USC §1308](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/1308) prohibits the import, export, or interstate sale of cat or dog fur:

> (1) In general
>
> It shall be unlawful for any person to—
>
> (A) import into, or export from, the United States any dog or cat fur product; or
>
> (B) introduce into interstate commerce, manufacture for introduction into interstate commerce, sell, trade, or advertise in interstate commerce, offer to sell, or transport or distribute in interstate commerce in the United States, any dog or cat fur product.

A brief summary of state laws can be found [this article at the Animal Legal & Historical Center:](https://www.animallaw.info/article/detailed-discussion-fur-animals-and-fur-production)

> A handful of states have laws concerning dog and cat fur.   Alabama, Delaware,   New Jersey, New York, Pennsylvania, and Virginia prohibit trade in domestic dog or cat fur.   Virginia also prohibits killing a dog or cat for its fur, while Florida prohibits killing a dog or cat with the “sole” intention of either selling or giving away the pelt of the animal.  In Oregon, a person cannot buy or sell dog or cat fur that is obtained from “a process that kills or maims the cat or dog.”

---

### UK:

In the UK, the trade in cat & dog fur was banned by the [The Cat and Dog Fur (Control of Import, Export and Placing on the Market) Regulations 2008](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2008/2795/contents/made), which were in turn passed to follow [EU Regulation #1523/2007:](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32007R1523)

> The placing on the market and the import to, or export from, the Community of cat and dog fur, and products containing such fur shall be prohibited.

More information about the legal consequences and enforcement of this law can be found at [this review article](https://www.inbrief.co.uk/animal-law/cat-and-dog-fur-trade/).

---

Finally, note that Cruella de Vil's actions did not involve *trade* in dog or cat fur;  she acquired most of the puppies via legal means, and was planning to kill and skin them for her own personal use, not to sell the resulting articles to other parties.  As such, I believe that her planned course of action would have been legal in the UK and in all US states except Virginia.  The only unquestionably illegal act she undertook was directing Jasper & Horace to steal Pongo's and Perdita's puppies.

Comment: Presumably, except for states that explicitly outlaw all trade in such furs (Alabama, Delaware etc.), trading dog/cat furs _within_ a state would be legal?

Comment: Of note: the history of *why* these laws came into existence mostly stems from these products being imported from Asia and the means by which those products were produced. The laws were essentially created to stop the atrocities and mislabeling occurring there by blocking them from being sold in other countries, *not* because anyone actually cared if you killed a dog or cat for personal use of fur or food. This was actually further expanded in the US via this bill: https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6720/text (signed by President in December)

Comment: Further complicating the matter, is that, both versions of the film, it would possibly not only be legal for trade, but highly valuable:  The Animated film doesn't give a year, but looks to be around 40s-61 (year of release) given the style of the cars used.   The live action remake was deliberately stated to be a modern retelling placing it firmly in 1998.  Had the hypothetical coat been remade, it would possibly be legal as it predated the a 2008 law.  Not sure if UK uses Grandfathering, but Grandfathered goods in the U.S. are extremely valuable as they are legally ownable illegal products